# Column resource not found

Tags: azure, kql, azure-monitor

I want list orphaned disk on my Azure but in the result I obtain this message :

'where' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'Resources'

[image]

I have taken the kql from internet and everybody use Resource has column to get result , I want to know why in my azure there is this error;

The column has the name changed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your workspace (or database) does not have a table or function called "Resources", you need to check the table list in the connection pane and see the tables you have, here is an example:
[image]

Comment: I am also struggling with this. I guess the OP wanted to understand how can he fetch the Resources, rather than confirming it is not working